# Not able to download attachment from Azure Devops rest API using Postman

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, postman, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Postman to hit azure devops Rest API for downloading the attachments.(fig)
Even after filling proper header, params it is showing `{ "count": 1, "value": { "Message": "The request is invalid." } }`.

I am tried all most all the technique mention on stack overflow but none of them is working.
My goal is to download attachment from devops workitem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you used the `Work Item ID` in the request URL, it is not correct, it should be the `Attachment ID`.

To get the `Attachment ID`, you need to use the REST API to get it first.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/orgname/proname/_apis/wit/workitems/<Work Item ID>?$expand=all&api-version=6.0
```

[image]

Copy the `Attachment ID` above, then use it in the API below, it works for me.

[image]